# Subsampling Scale Image View

Tags: android

Does any one know how can we send an array of images to the '**SubsamplingScaleImageView**' class...
It works fine with one, but... I just want to open like 3 or 4 images and swipe between them and I just can't find a way...

Any help would be great!

Here is my (simple) code:

MainActivity:

```
private int[] myImages;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.p01, R.drawable.p02
    };

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.p01));
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a `ViewPager` or a `RecyclerView` to swipe between a series of `SubsamplingScaleImageView` widgets.

Comment: Got it! Yes... 'ViewPager' solved the problem. Thanks CommonsWare!